# I want to user 'substr' in an if statement in mysql

Tags: mysql, if-statement, substr

I want to user `substr` in an 'if-statement' in mysql.

for example...

```
if(substr(member, 1, 2 ) = 'A1','one','two') as member
```

When I use substr in the 'select-statement', the result is good.
But the above query will cause an error.

> Can not 'substr' be used in an 'if-statement'?

Is there any other way?

===============================

member field value = 'A1/B1/C1/D1' or 'A2/B2/C2/D2' or 'A1/B2/C2/D1'........

A1,B1,C1,D1 = yes , A2,B2,C2,D2 = no

I would like to change this as follows.

member1
answerA = yes
answerB = yes
answerC = yes
answerD = yes

member2
answerA = no
answerB =no
answerC =no
answerD =no

member3
answerA = yes
answerB =no
answerC =yes
answerD =no

Comment: Post your complete query with sample and desired data set

Comment: Do you mean an `IF` statement in a stored procedure? See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html) for the syntax of `IF` statements, they're nothing like the `IF()` function in a query.

Comment: I'M so sorry..... I omit the comma........... Queries work fine....

Comment: You should flag the question for closing because it was just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) statement:

```
SELECT IF (member REGEXP '^A1', 'one', 'two') AS member FROM table;
```

Comment: That's equivalent to `SUBSTR(member, 2, 2)`, since SQL indexes are 1-based.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine

```
SELECT if(substr("TEST DATA", 1, 2 ) = 'A1','one','two') as member
```